# pass value from django views to js function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models

I have used a function which will open a tab on press of a button and those button will be generated by using values from django
I am able to call those values out site the js function but when I try to pass them as parameter in js function my page shows blank.

**index.html**

```
 {% for exp in experience %}
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, {{exp.e_name}})" id="defaultOpen">{{exp.e_name}}</button>
 {% endfor %}
```

**app.js**

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

kindly guide me how can I pass ***exp.e_name*** to js function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass location as `string`, like:

```
{% for exp in experience %}
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '{{exp.e_name}}')" id="defaultOpen">{{exp.e_name}}</button>
{% endfor %}
```